# Is there a simpler way to compute the least squares solution for real measurements of a complex system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, least-squares

I have the following problem: $$b = \Re\{Ax\} + w,$$
where $A$ and $x$ are complex, and $b$ and $w$ are real.
I'd like to compute the least squares solution, i.e., $$\hat{x} = \arg\,\min_x\|b-\Re\{Ax\}\|_2^2.$$

I know if everything were real or complex, the solution would be $(A^H A)^{-1}A^H b$. Is there a similar form that works for real measurements of a complex system?

The only thing I can think of is splitting $A$ and $x$ into real/imaginary components, as in
$$A_r = \Re\{A\}, ~A_i = \Im\{A\}, ~A_c = [A_r, A_i] $$
$$x_r = \Re\{x\}, ~x_i = \Im\{x\}, ~x_c = [x_r^T,x_i^T]^T$$
so that $$b = A_c x_c + w.$$
Then the solution would be $(A_c^T A_c)^{-1}A_c^T b$.
However, the matrix is bigger now and takes longer to compute.
Also, if I wanted to apply some sort of regularization to $x$, I would be dealing with the real/imaginary components separately.